# White space below footer (and body) in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I add in CSS:

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I got big white space below footer for some reason, but just in Chrome. I was test on a few browsers and everything fine.

Is this some browser bug or the problem is something else?

You can take a look at http://fc-translations.ch

---

**UPDATE**

I tried all the given suggestions below but neither solution is working. I was researching further and realized that the problem is not caused by adding 'overflow-x: hidden;' on 'body' element (or 'min-width: 960px;' which is mentioned in comment).

Omission happened because almost every time when you try to disable something for 'body' element in Chrome's inspector (F12), white space disappears.

I still can't figure out what is causing this problem. The white space is not even in the 'body' element but, as I can see, it appears below the 'body' in Chrome.

Any idea?

Comment: Is rare, but when I disable the min-width: 960px; from the "body"... The space below dissapear :S

Comment: The question is updated...

Comment: Your demo url is no longer working... mind reposting it?

Comment: my mistake, sorry about that...link is changed...

Comment: please post your markup here, not in an external link (for this exact reason). This question will be void if that link breaks for future readers.

Comment: That is a little tricky, this website was created through Drupal and theme was created using Omega Tools...

Comment: As Gorostad mentioned try removing `body.front, body.page-node-18{
overflow-x: hidden;
}` and add `.page{overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: There might be a hidden div with greater height than its parent. Deal with that div.

Comment: Take a look at this github issue: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/pull/60#issuecomment-40238961. Basically, WOW applies before Chrome can finish its animations. Something like that should help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem:

The problem appears to be coming from the animation `bounceInUp` being applied to `.la-tekst a`.

The animation does the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
        0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateY(2000px)}
        60%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:translateY(-30px)}
        80%{-webkit-transform:translateY(10px)}
        100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0)
    }
}
```

Perhaps it was a side effect of the `inline-block` (`.la-tekst a` is set to `display:inline-block;`), but the anchor element was occupying both its original space, and the space set from the 0% of the `bounceInUp` animation.

### Solutions:

Applying `overflow:hidden` to any of the following will work

(pick one selector)

```
.page {overflow:hidden;}
.section-content {overflow:hidden;}
.zone-content-wrapper {overflow:hidden;}
.region-content {overflow:hidden;}
.region-content-inner {overflow:hidden;}
.block-block-1 {overflow:hidden;}
.la-tekst {overflow:hidden;}
```

#### or

Change the bounding area that the anchor tag occupies

```
.la-tekst a {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.la-tekst a {
    display: block;
}
```

The two suggestions I provided will fix the problem... The first one will hide child elements bleeding past its height or (including the super-animated anchor tag).

The second solution will change the bounding area that the anchor tag occupies, so that it no longer occupies its animated space and its original space at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your css

```
.page{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in your head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var docheight = jQuery(document).height();
var bodyheight = jQuery('body').height();
var bodywidth = jQuery('body').width();


/*alert(docheight+'--'+bodyheight);*/

if (bodyheight < docheight && bodywidth >= 1000) {

    $(".footer-class-name").css('position',"absolute");

    }


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it.
By adding the style of footer div:style="position:absolute;width:100%;"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to strip out any browser default styling with a normaliser such as http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line in your css file. The white space will not be displayed:

```
div#goog-gt-tt{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove CSS:

```
body.front, body.page-node-18{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Add CSS:

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.front, body.page-node-18{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Try remove body{min-width:960px;}

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of testing I realized that if you don't call the `new WOW().init();` then the page displays OK in Chrome without the extra space below the footer.

So that tells me that there is some sort of incompatibility with your layout and the way the WOW library works in Chrome.

Maybe you can focus your efforts there or raise a bug report in WOW's github page if its indeed an issue with WOW and Chrome at https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

Answer (score 1):

Define in css

```
#omega-media-query-dummy
{
float:left;
}
```

hope Fully it help you

Comment: This seems like the easiest way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

**Set position to relative; on the body tag.**

Edit: I tried both chrome and Chrome canary. White space disappears.